# Its possible to message received being out of order or limited using Netty?

Tags: java, tcp, netty

Well, Im using netty framework java, to handle messages by concox equipment protocol, the messages received by my application seems to be different than the expected.

The message received is like

EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD **0D 0A 78 78** 1F 12 13 0A 1C 0F 12 1D EF BF BD

And the expected should be

**78 78** 23 12 10 03 1D 0F 17 12 C7 02 6B 6E 38 0C 39 71 00 0B 15 0E 01 CC 00 24 95 00 13 93 00
02 3D 7C 01 09 27 35 **0D 0A**

**78 78** is the start bit
**0D 0A** is the stop bit

What this could be? We use this application base for a lot of protocols and they work
The support says that could be a problem of buffer connection, but i don't know how could it be.

I can handle the problem of the start and stop bit at the wrong position.
But the message expected stills much bigger.

The doc link is http://www.iconcox.in/images/tr-06-protocol.pdf

Our code

```
public abstract class ExtendedObjectDecoder implements ChannelUpstreamHandler {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void handleUpstream(
            ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelEvent evt) throws Exception {
        if (!(evt instanceof MessageEvent)) {
            ctx.sendUpstream(evt);
            return;
        }

        MessageEvent e = (MessageEvent) evt;
        Object originalMessage = e.getMessage();

        System.out.println((String) originalMessage);
    }
}
```

Pileline

```
@Override
    public void initTrackerServers(List<TrackerServer> serverList) {
        serverList.add(new TrackerServer(new ServerBootstrap()) {
            @Override
            protected void addSpecificHandlers(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
                pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new CharacterDelimiterFrameDecoder(4096, "$", "\0"));
                pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder());
                pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder());
                pipeline.addLast("objectDecoder", new EquipProtocolDecoder(EquipProtocol.this));
            }
        });
        serverList.add(new TrackerServer(new ConnectionlessBootstrap()) {
            @Override
            protected void addSpecificHandlers(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
                pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder());
                pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder());
                pipeline.addLast("objectDecoder", new EquipProtocolDecoder(EquipProtocol.this));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your pipeline ?

Comment: Added, this is what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty is designed to be a simplified layer over the actual protocol, and thus inherits many semantics from it.

One important semantic is that TCP is a *stream* based protocol, meaning that when you read any data, you get all the data in order, but the data might be spread out over multiple packets, or all data might be in the same packet.

Your code does not deal with this properly, and this is causing your issues.

What happened in your case is that the remote send 2 "protocol specific packets", and after reading, these packets where mixed up over "tcp packets"

- Before: `Aaaaa Bbbbb Cccc Ddddd`
- After: `Aaa aaaBbbbCccccDdddd`

*You need something to reconstruct the original messages again.*

At the moment, your pipeline exists of a `StringDecoder`, followed by your business handler. Unfortunately, `StringDecoder` is not suited up to the task of handling raw incoming data, and could [actually cause corruption](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4690) when handling raw incoming data.

Fortunately for you, "tr-06" has a length field in every packet. (Detecting the presence of a start and stop bit is unreliable, since they could also be inside a packet) We can use this length field to decode the "stream of bytes" to "packets again. Lets gather some information the the documentation of the protocol:

> **iv.Data Packet Format**
>
> The communication is transferred asynchronously in
>   bytes.The total length of packets is (10+N) Bytes
>
> ...
>
> **4.2.Packet Length**
>
> Length  =  Protocol  Number  +  Information  Content  +  Information  Serial  Number  +  Error  Check, totally (5+N)Bytes, because the Information Content is a variable length field.

We eventually want to use a pre-build solution for "framing" the bytes, so lets read into the documentation of [`DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`](https://netty.io/3.10/api/index.html?org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html). We can see that the example of "3 bytes length field at the end of 5 bytes header, do not strip header" closely matches what we need, but isn't quite it. Lets calculate the correct data based on these examples:

We see in the protocol example that the length field comes after the start bit, and the start bit is 2 bytes long, so the offset becomes 2

```
lengthFieldOffset   = 2
```

According to the documentation, the packet length field is 1, meaning that it supports packets up to 255 bytes in length

```
lengthFieldLength   = 1
```

This is a hard one to calculate, Netty assumes that the packet length is all the bytes after the length fields is contained inside the packet, so lets calculate it from netties perspective, and see how it lines up.

Netty: `1 + N + 2 + 2 + 2`
Protocol: `1 N + 2 + 2`

```
lengthAdjustment    = 2
```

We need to adjust the length field by 2

We don't want to strip any bytes (you might want to enable this later if you are not interested in the start and stop bits)

```
initialBytesToStrip = 0
```

**Lets put this together:**

```
        @Override
        protected void addSpecificHandlers(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
            pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(255, 2, 1, 2, 0));
            pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast("objectDecoder", new EquipProtocolDecoder(EquipProtocol.this));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the explanation, really helps me to understand how to work with this kind of information. I tried it here, and the order of the hex ins't wrong anymore, but i still have some problem with the information,

Comment: 78781f12130b01122a19efbfbd0054130e066fefbfbd2800efbfbdefbfbd02efbfbd0501240016450031d2800d0a  In the middle of the information appears to many substrings like EFBDBD, is this associated with our problem?

Comment: I see the StringEncode issue, but i don't know how to solve

Comment: @wagnermps Do you need to decide all binary data to strings? If not, just work with the bytebufs themselves, then you won't get a y data loss from the process of unknown binary data to Unicode string (a String in Java is not binary safe, unlike in other languages)

Comment: so, all i need is removing the string encode/decode from pipeline? All i need to add some other? I cant find notthing about it

Comment: @wagnermps you have to remove both string encoder and decoder. Your message handler will look like `Object originalMessage = e.getMessage(); System.out.println((Bytebuf) originalMessage);`, and will show on screen as a bed dump for debugging purposes

Comment: It works, thanks @FerryBig, im not running Netty 4+ to use ByteBuf, but i finded a way after your tip